# Fair Sorting two arrays by values in another array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

In ruby, I need to sort an array that contains ten hashes, in to two arrays.

Each hash has an entry named "points"

I need to sort the two arrays to be most fair on both parts.

thus if one hash has 1200 points, and another has 1220, and the rest 1000, I need to sort it out so the ones with 1200 and 1220 points doesnt get in the same array, if you follow :)

Hope the good folks of aardvark can help me!

Comment: That is not a sorting problem, that is a partitioning problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). It is NP-complete, but according to Wikipedia "there are heuristics that solve the problem in many instances". They do describe or link to some of these approaches (unfortunately not in ready-to-use pseudocode). I guess if you only have 10 elements in your array, an exhaustive search of all 1024 possibilities is feasible.

Comment: Damn, this was a much harder question than I first realized. I read what I could understand from the article(s) - But i can't really figure it out. Could you please point me in whatever direction you think might be the best in my situation?

And of course, thank you very much for your quick reply :)

Comment: You could try all 1024 combinations, and take the one that is most fair. (You can abort the search if you find a perfect partition).